# building a select query to scan specified columns by the user

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create create an API which allow users to query the database based on whatever columns they wish to use, by passing the column name as parameter.

```
@app.route('/api/restaurants/search1/',methods=['GET'])
def search():
    col = request.args['col']
    key = request.args['key']
    restaurant = Restaurant.query.filter(Restaurant.menu_type.like("%"+key+"%")).all()
    return jsonify(json_list=[i.serialize for i in restaurant])
```

I am trying to replace "Menu_type" which is the current column by whatever the user enters for the variable "col" any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function. To avoid cases when object has requested attribute but it is not a table column (a method for example) check `Restaurant.__table__.c` — collection of table columns:

```
@app.route('/api/restaurants/search1/',methods=['GET'])
def search():
    col = request.args['col']
    key = request.args['key']
    if col in Restaurant.__table__.c:
        restaurant = Restaurant.query.filter(getattr(Restaurant, col).like("%"+key+"%")).all()
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Restaurant table doesn`t have column %s' % col)
    return jsonify(json_list=[i.serialize for i in restaurant])
```